# Error message: You have requested: bcrypt-ruby ~> 3.0.1 The bundle currently has bcrypt-ruby locked at 3.0.1.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running my ruby on rails app on amazone elastic beanstalk but I am having the error as stated in the title.

I am using has_secure_password, hence I've uncommented the following inside my gemfile

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```

I pushed my code to elastic beanstalk and got the following erorr:

```
You have requested: bcrypt-ruby ~> 3.0.0 
The bundle currently has bcrypt-ruby locked at 3.0.1. 
Try running `bundle update bcrypt-ruby` (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

I've tried changing my gem to the following but it doesn't work either.

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.1'
```

Comment: when I look at my Gemfile.lock I noticed the following under specs

bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1-x86-mingw32)

but the following under dependencies:

bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by modifying Gemfile.lock file. I changed

```
specs:
     bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1-x86-mingw32)
```

into

```
specs:
     bcrypt-ruby (3.0.0)
```

I encountered other library issue, what I did is the same as above, removing mingw32.